# Is there a way to use "git log --oneline" filtering by commit hash while keeping the branch names?

Tags: linux, git, shell

I was looking for a way to highlight a specific commit hash when using `git log --oneline`, and I managed to do that by using:

```sh
# consider that 000000000 is the first 9 digits of the commit hash
git log --oneline | grep --color=always -E '^|000000000' | less -R
```

This actually works in a very similar way to simply `git log --oneline` and it indeed highlights the commit `000000000`. The only problem though, is that it ends up losing all the information regarding my branches that `git log --oneline` gives me.

---

Examples:

```sh
# input:
git log --oneline

# output:
000000000 (myRemote/myBranch) my commit message
```

```sh
# input:
git log --oneline | grep --color=always -E '^|000000000' | less -R

# output:
000000000 my commit message
```

---

While the latter example comes with a highlighted `000000000`, it lacks the `(myRemote/myBranch)` information.

So, is there a way to modify the input I'm using so that I can get both the highlight and branch info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the flag `--decorate` to your log, it'll do the job, I just tried it (git version 2.21.0.windows.1).

---

Optionnally, you might want to make an alias to which you pass the hash as a parameter, for convenience :

```
git config --global alias.find '!f() { git log --oneline --decorate | grep --color=always -E "(^|${1})"; }; f'
```

...and then when you search for commit `deadbea7dad`, you just type

```
git find deadbea7dad
```

Comment: @Roveir and thanks to you, since I'm gonna use this highlighting myself!